# Getting parent value of Firebase node based on known child value?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been trying to get the value of a parent node based on the child node's value in Swift. I've read different answers and tried implementing them but none of them work.

The current structure of my Firebase db is:

```
- leaderboard
  - 0
    - score: 123
    - name: "School #1"
  - 1
    - score: 14323
    - name: "School #2"
```

The code I've been trying is:

```
let query = Database.database().reference().child("leaderboard").queryOrdered(byChild: "name").queryEqual(toValue: self.userSchool)
        query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:
        { snapshot in
                for child in snapshot.children
                {
                    let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                    let key = snap.key
                    print("School key is: " + key)
                }
        })
```

If I comment out the .queryEqual(toValue: self.userSchool), the code runs and returns every key, but if I leave that part in, nothing happens at all.

How can I make the .queryEqual part work to return 0 if the school is School #1?

Answer (score 0):

You could denormalize your data in such a way your query is easy to build.

Together with the data structure you already have you would have another node (ie. another data structure) like:

```
- leaderboardBySchool 
  - School #1
    - id: 0
  - School #2
    - id: 1
```

With NoSQL database you should not hesitate to duplicate data in such a way your queries are easier (and also faster) to execute.

---

Following your comment, you could have a node like that:

```
- leaderboardBySchool
  -autogeneratedId1 
    - name: School #1
    - id: 0
  -autogeneratedId2
    - name: School #2
    - id: 1
```

And would still be easier than with only one node.

---

Something like that will give you the id based on the School name

```
var leaderboardBySchoolRef =firebase.database()  
.ref('leaderboardBySchool')
.orderByChild('name')
.startAt('School2')
.limitToFirst(1);

leaderboardBySchoolRef.once('value').then(function (snaps) {
    snaps.forEach(function(child) {
        console.log(child.val().id) 
    });
});
```

Comment: unfortunately the school names involve characters that are invalid for firebase keys, and i'm trying to avoid duplicating the list of schools across the db as theres a decent number of them :/ I appreciate the idea though, and I'll consider it

Comment: I think your revision would still leave me with the same problem. I can't access the parent node key, in your example it would be autogeneratedId1. The code I have isn't returning that value, and I would have to do the same to implement your solution as I only know the school name initially.

Comment: @user2928362 Can't you use an orderByChild with this new data structure? You should be able to find the node based on the school name and then get the id

Comment: @user2928362 Have a look at my answer, I've adapted it with one solution

Comment: I converted your solution to swift, but it just returned an error stating that id isn't a valid key, presumably because the code isn't searching below the level of the autogeneratedIds

Comment: @user2928362 Can you update your Question with your new code?